# What does "parameterized manner" mean in this context

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time understanding the b) point from the following statement.

*The base of a triangle has a length of 25 cm. Its height is 12 cm. This results in an area of (25 x 12) / 2.*

*a)What values can be considered parameters for the above statement?*

*b) Rewrite the statement in a parameterized manner.*

*c)Which of the above values can be named input values and which can be called output values.*

I guess for a) the answer is values can be consideres the length, height and the area numbers.

And for c) Input values can be considered the length and the height numbers, as for area is considered the ouput.

I'm having trouble understanding the b) statement, what does it mean to write it in a parameterized manner ? Translate it into code ?

I'm trying to learn java and prepare for a test and any help you guys can give is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: what did your teacher said when you asked them to clarify this part of the homework?

Comment: ...also I think you've got [quite a poor advice at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080995/what-does-parameterized-manner-mean-in-this-context-java#comment77135228_45080995) - sorry about that

Comment: It's for a test for a intervew as a QA Analyst and they find basic java knowledge a plus. No teacher involved.

Comment: so, what did interviewer say when you asked them?

Comment: crossposting is highly frowned upon. This was downvoted on StackOverflow for being out of scope (as it is here too.) It is closer to a SO question IF and only if you try coding it yourself and find a specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement gives you three values - length, height, and area. The Area can be calculated from the first two (formula is given).

So if you wanted to create a function from this (which I assume is what they are trying to teach you), you would have to pass length and height into the function and get the area back. But, step by step:

> a) What values can be considered parameters for the above statement?

Parameters are the input values, the variables needed for a statement, function or formula to give you a result. In this case, they are length and height - the area isn't needed because it can be calculated from the other two.

> b) Rewrite the statement in a parameterized manner.

I assume there's an example for what they expect that to look like in your course/class material - I can only guess at that. If I had to do it, it would end up looking something like this:

The base of a triangle has a length of l = 25 cm. Its height is h = 12 cm. This results in an area A = (l x h) / 2.

> c) Which of the above values can be named input values and which can be called output values.

Well, as I said above - the "input values" are the values you put into your calculation, and the "output values" are what the calculation puts out. So height and length are input variables, while the area is the output variable.

Comment: Thank you sir. I got my hands of a few examples that I might get for a job interview as QA Analyst, and from all the other simple examples this ones puzzled me because I could not find anything easy to understand. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know why, but I'd never seen the commonality between algebra and programming. Now that I think about it, it makes perfect sense. Both are all about abstractions.

Comment: I really like this answer-clear and concise.

Comment: @ChrisG Computers and Math are extremely intertwined. The early computer scientists were basically just mathematicians. (Which is why everything has mathematical names for example 'functions;)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble understanding the b) statement, what does it mean to write it in a parameterized manner ? Translate it into code ?

IMHO you are supposed to *prepare* the statement for translation into code.

Just replace the actual numbers with *place holder names*.

Comment: is this merely your opinion or you can back it up somehow?

Comment: @Timothy Thanks for your input and time, I guess it does make sense.